# linphone_call_take_video_snapshot saved empty file

Tags: ios, linphone

I am working on a project based on **Linphone-iPhone**, the project requires taking a snapshot of current video stream (both in and out).

I've found this '*linphone_call_take_video_snapshot*' in liblinphone and gave it a try. 
The code was simple and running without any error, but the size of the saved file is always **0 kb**!

Here's the code:

```
- (void)capture {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *file_path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"snapshot.jpeg"];
    LinphoneCall *call = linphone_core_get_current_call([LinphoneManager getLc]);
    const char *c_file_path = [file_path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    int ret = linphone_call_take_video_snapshot(call, c_file_path);

    if (ret >= 0 && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file_path]) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file_path], nil,nil,nil);
    }
}
```

Does *linphone_call_take_video_snapshot* really work? If so, what have I been doing wrong?

Comment: Is video call working ??

Comment: I have more interesting problem that it returns -1 for video call, I could not understand the reason.